# Problema con HAXM (no puedo instalarlo en Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio

Buen día.
Por más que intento instalar HAXM en mi computadora (y que el propio instalador me dice que se instaló) al usar Android Studio me dice que debo actualizar la versión de HAXM (y eso que puse la versión más reciente de acuerdo con gitHub).
Tengo la suposición de que tendrá que ver con la ruta de la carpeta en que está instalado pero no sé cómo checar eso, además que el propio instalador de Android Studio no me deja instalarlo.
Ya hice el paso que se hace en el Boot (para habilitar algo de la virtualización) y ni así.
Agradeceré mucho me puedan ayudar.
[image: Pide actualizar HAXM]

[image: Fallo al instalarse]